# Is there a standard way to rig a humanoid?

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation, art, rigging

I am using some placeholder humanoid models for my game, which will be replaced later.  I am concerned that when I replace them, they will not work with my animations, due to different rigging.

Is there a standard rigging that artists use for humanoids?  Such as, is there always a the same number of body parts attached in the same hierarchy, or does this vary based on the artist/studio?  If there is a standard, what is it?  If there isn't, how can I ensure that my animations and models play nice?

[image]

I use Unity, if it's relevant.

*Disclaimer:  I am not an artist, and I have no idea what I am talking about.  Please feel free to ask for clarification.*

Comment: [You can get a pretty good clue from the bones listed in Unity's avatar mapping window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Avatar.html), or by opening up one of their free sample humanoid characters and examining how it's been set up. [Unity can also compensate for some variation in a humanoid rig through retargeting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html).